# What is the benefits of modules in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, module

In Google app engine, what is the benefits of using modules instead separate applications?

For example If am already having an application named "Example" for my example.com and now I need new blog feature for blog.example.com.

Now Which is better? New module named "blog" in "Example" application OR New application named "Example Blog" like that?

And Note I concern about Google's Free Quota for App Engine too. **If I use separate applications I can get Free Quotas for each Individual application. But If I used modules I should manage both example.com and blog.example.com in the same Free Quota usage**.

So which option is best on Price Comparison and which is best in Performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are operates under same AppId, that mean that they will:

- share same Datastore for data
- same Task Queue for interoperability
- same configuration for other Google Cloud services (BigQuery, Storage, etc)

There is not difference in Performance, separate apps or separate modules of same app could have as much resources as they need.

As about price, then two apps could be little bit cheaper that two modules, because of Free Quota. But I don't think there is a significant difference for most apps.